# Override IExternal command with another one

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I am currently looking for some hacks to communicate between external commands:
what i want to do is: Use an external command to modify the others to be able to "configure" theses. 
Why do i want to do that ? 
Revit has not a sort of "Command id" for types creation, so i am now wondering if: I can have an external command who can be used for every type (FamilySymbol) in a Revit Project.
OR can create a command who can create another one.

I know this is confusing but i am looking for solutions since yesterday and it seems like a dead end for me.

Thanks for your responses and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why you need two commands for that. You can implement one single command that enables the user to choose any kind of family symbol they wish to place. You (and your add-in code) need to be aware that different kinds of symbols take different kinds of placement options, and select the corresponding [appropriate `NewFamilySymbol` method overload](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/01/newfamilyinstance-overloads.html).

Comment: I needed to be able to store the family instance to use it as a plugin. I did it with a "hack": create file.  Now i need to be able to create a shortcut.xml file to be able to import it from revit UI. Thanks for your response. Now i suppose i can create an identic xml file like the one who can be exported to be able to import them to add them from existing ones, am i in the right way?